# Rails load from activation token does not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I try to load a user from an activation token in order to activate him but somehow it fails:

```
us = User.find(7)
us.activation_token
 => "BqgLeANnMj9jCCsTp2hy" 
@user = User.load_from_activation_token(us.activation_token)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (activation_token = 'BqgLeANnMj9jCCsTp2hy') LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

Although user exists and is opening and has an activation token, load_from_activation_token cannot find it. Is there any other possibility to activate a user?

Comment: Have you seen this issue on github ? https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
us = User.find(7)
token = us.activation_token
 => "BqgLeANnMj9jCCsTp2hy" 

    @user = User.find_by_activation_token(token)

    or 

    @user = User.find_by(activation_token: token)

    or

    @user = User.where(activation_token: token).first
```